# QJsonArray append() method - complexity O(n²)?

Tags: qt, complexity-theory, qlist

```
QElapsedTimer timer;
QJsonArray jarray;      

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    jarray.append(QJsonValue());
qDebug()<<timer.restart();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    jarray.append(QJsonValue());
qDebug()<<timer.restart();

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    jarray.append(QJsonValue());
qDebug()<<timer.restart();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    jarray.append(QJsonValue());
qDebug()<<timer.restart();
```

Output :

```
5
782
88603
267695
```

It seems like complexity of my loop is O(n²). A list append() method has to be O(1). So O(n) for a loop of n elements. WTF?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I would delete the content of `jarray` before each loop you used because when it comes to the fourth loop, the array already contains 1000+10000+100000 elements. Does it give a different results?

Comment: JSON is one of the least efficient data formats, only XML is worse. You'd typically use a more efficient container for your data, and only use JSON for export / interop, not actually doing such operations on it.

Comment: It probably doesn't reserve any extra capacity, so every append reallocates the entire growing array.

Comment: @Vahancho It is the same if I clear jarray between loops

Comment: @ddriver  I need Json format... Even if there is no reserved memory, the complexity of the append() method has to be O(1), so O(n) for a loop of n elements...

Comment: @NiHoT I think what ddriver is saying is that the complexity of a reallocation is also O(n), so if you don't have reserve capacity, and you end up reallocating every iteration, it becomes n^2.

Comment: @NiHoT "I need Json format" that doesn't mean you have to work in it. Besides `QJsonArray` is not really JSON until you make it into a `QJsonDocument::toJson()`